# How can i save a string into a pointer and redefine it using malloc? C

Tags: c, string, pointers, memory, realloc

I'm in a loop and i want to save readed values from a fifo in a variable.

```
    char *tmp=NULL;
    char *opts=NULL;
    char break_[]="DONE\n";
    int byte_;
    while(1){
        pipe_r = open(pipe_r_n, O_RDONLY);
        if(pipe_r==-1){
            exit(100);
        }
        read(pipe_r,&byte,sizeof(int));
        opts=malloc((byte+1)*sizeof(char));
        if (!opts) {
            free(opts);
            opts = NULL;
            close(pipe_r);
            exit(102);
        }
        read(pipe_r,opts,byte*sizeof(char));
        printf("ho letto: %s",opts);
        close(pipe_r);
        if(strcmp(opts,break_)==0){
            break;
        }
        free(opts);opts=NULL;tmp=NULL;
    }
    free(opts);opts=NULL;tmp=NULL;
```

The byte_ int is the number of bytes following that needs to be read. 
It says 0 byte readed in the begging but also printing(read not waiting(?)).Then it reads line with the right number of bytes and after that nothing but with the same number of bytes... and sometimes it reapeat itself instead of nothing...
That's the client:

```
    fd=fopen(argv[3],"r"); 
    if(fd==NULL){
        exit(100);
    }
    char *line=NULL;
    size_t len=0;
    ssize_t read;
    int byte;

    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fd)) != -1) {
        printf("%s\n",line);
        pipe_r = open(pipe_r_n, O_WRONLY);
        if(pipe_r==-1){
            exit(100);
        }
        byte=strlen(line);
        byte;
        write(pipe_r,&byte,sizeof(int));
        write(pipe_r,line,sizeof(char)*(strlen(line)));
        close(pipe_r);
        if(strcmp(line,"EXIT\n")==0){
            break;
        }
   }
```

Comment: Not sure why realloc().  You are freeing your pointer every time through the loop.  Also, you cannot call `strcmp` legally on a freed pointer.

Comment: Yea that was an error of rewriting i'm sorry. I use realloc because i want to keep my pointer up for every cicle. Why is it wrong?

Comment: Pretty sure that edit is wrong as well.  The free line should not exist in 2 places - it should be outside the while loop only, though in truth, it would probably function OK now.

Comment: Now as to `realloc` use: you can call` malloc/calloc` and `free` every loop or `realloc`, but `realloc` is generally reserved for when you want to preserve the contents of the buffer during the reallocation.  You do not, so this will involve needless extra work.  Further, calling `free()` every loop makes `realloc` completetly unneeded.  This does not explain the behavior you are seeing now though.  It might be a good idea to check the return codes of your `read` functions to be sure they are reading as much information as you expect.

Comment: oh i understood now, but i always have to set the pointer to null after the free right? and the free outside the loop is because when the cmp makes a break it doesn't free the argc.

Comment: You do not need to set to free always, but it is a good practice to do so.  If you don't set to free and accidentally use the "dangling pointer" later, it can cause Undefined Behavior.

Comment: In your code, I am also not sure why you need 2 pointers.  Just using `opts` looks to be sufficient and will make management simpler.

Comment: yea i keeped a sort of "backup" copy of the string, but with malloc implementation i deleted tmp

Comment: now i'm trying the same code with opts=malloc(byte_*sizeof(char))

Comment: You should repost the changed code and double check that it still fails.  I also still stand next to the `read` return value checks.  If what you read in does not have a `\0` terminator on the end, your string printing printf will fail...

Comment: yea now i'm changing and inserting +1 in the byte var for malloc end char,but still error...now i edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Michael Dorgan pointed out, you need to add `opts[byte] = '\0'` after reading the string.

The last byte of you malloced area is always uninitialized (could be any leftover value). And since you have frequent malloc and free behavior. It is likely your heap memory is spraying with non-zero characters. Therefore, when you call `printf`, you leak strings from the previous loop run.

Comment: i added that and i read everithing well now, the only problem left is that i get multiple reading for some lines,also  empty read and then actual read for the first 3 line...

Comment: I would suggest print out your `byte` value each run for debugging. The information isn't enough to pinpoint the source of problem

Comment: i do that and it says 0 in the begging but also printing(read not waiting(?)).Then it reads line with the right number of bytes and after that nothing but with the same number of bytes... and sometimes it reapeat itself instead of nothing...

Comment: I suggest study your input file well. You probably understand the format wrong.

Comment: it's a regular text file... i also post the reader, maybe i'm failing there but it prints everything clear and has the same open-close...

Comment: It another problem now and it should be in another thread. `read(pipe_r,&byte,sizeof(int));` probably did not succeed when you close the pipe on the other side. Try move `open` and `close` outside the loop.

Comment: You are right, i'm sorry and thank you for the precious help man...